# ¿Cómo puedo resolver el problema 'Mainfest merger failed' en Android Studio? Sólo me aparece al agregar firebase al proyecto

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo un problema y es que cuando intento compilar una aplicación en android studio me salta un error y no se compila, esto pasa solo al agregar firebase al proyecto, cabe destacar que antes no me pasaba esto.

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que si defines la versión 17 o posterior  de `Firebase`, esta ya hace uso de Android X:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
```

Puedes usar una versión anterior de Firebase pero **lo correcto sería migrar a `AndroidX` tu proyecto**.

**[Cómo migrar a AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate?hl=es-419)**